# Can I adapt an odds ratio into a simple percentage increase?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics

Apologies for my very rudimentary knowledge of statistics.

I have always worked with Odds ratios and referenced them as the relative risk change. I have now been advised that I need to report something in percentage format. For example, I have an odds ratio of 3.16; I used to think this just meant an increased risk of 216%, but having looked into this I no longer think this is correct. It seems that converting an Odds ratio to a non-relative percentage is a little more complicated.

Thus I'm unsure how to properly report these values, or even know if I am able to. For an example of 3 categories, with the first, cat 1, being the baseline (OR 1, and percentage chance of x occurring 7.8%), then cat. 2 and cat. 3 being 3.16 and 3.33 respectively, how would I adapt these into percentages where I can say 'being in category 2 means you have % chance of x' rather than stating it as a relative value?

Thanks in advance for anyone who can provide some help!